# Graphic novel about degraded future society and protagonist trapped(?) in a stronghold

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a "graphic novel" type story that I almost certainly saw in Heavy Metal magazine. Time frame would very likely be early to mid-80s.

It took place in a future where civilization was in dire decline, or very degraded. Not sure if it was completely post apocalyptic mainly because of the nature of the locale.  The protagonists were trapped(?), maintaining a stronghold(?) somewhere in the tropics at an air field, and my recollection was that it was a South American location, possibly mountainous in some panels of the story. The location may originally been an air museum because the male protagonists were all pilots of the WWII aircraft that were parked there and flew them in some sort of missions against the inevitable antagonist force that they had to contend with and it definitely pandered to adolescent fantasies.

The clincher for that last statement was that there were also a group of beautiful supermodels that were also trapped(?) in the same location. Again, I'm almost certain that it was in Heavy Metal, and I'm not 100% sure whether it was in color or black and white. It was in English.

My recollection was that it was current when I was reading it.
Can anyone point me to what it was? A series? A one shot?

I'd love to know the full story (about the author, about the plot and what became of the story), since the general situation was just over the top awesomeness for 15 year old who craved adventure and the approval of beautiful women.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Although this is already pretty detailed, this question might be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)